# how to work with navigation properly in javascript for button click?

Tags: javascript, navigation

I am trying to apply the code below to navigate. but the problem is, it is not working on a single click.
it starts working on second click. plase help me to understand the problem for not working on first click.

```
function handlePurchaseBtn() {
  document.getElementById('go-home-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location = 'https://www.google.com'
  })
}
```

Comment: What does your html look like? When do you call `handlePurchaseBtn()`?

Comment: i have tried the navigate function with a simple button after working on my project. but the result is same. – 
<body>
    <button id="go-home-btn" onclick="handlePurchaseBtn()">click me to navigate</button>

    <script>
        function handlePurchaseBtn() {
            document.getElementById('go-home-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
            window.location = 'https://www.google.com'
    })
}
    </script>
</body>

Comment: Please show what you've tried, include your html, and how you are calling `handlePurchaseButton()`. Add any additional code to your original question; code blocks in comments aren't easy to read.

Comment: <body>
    <button id="go-home-btn" onclick="handlePurchaseBtn()">click me to navigate</button>

    <script>
        function handlePurchaseBtn() {
            document.getElementById('go-home-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
            window.location = 'https://www.google.com'
    })
}
    </script>
</body>

Comment: Avoid defining event listeners inside functions, or handle appropriately (i.e: using options `{once: true}`). You can call a function multiple times, and you don't want multiple listeners to be attached.

Comment: The navigation function hasn't been added as of the first click. The first clicks adds that, subsequent clicks will execute that and navigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be the other way around - if that's the desired:

```js
function handlePurchaseBtn(evt) { 
  evt.preventDefault(); // If needed, to prevent a default browser action
  window.location = "https://www.google.com";
}

document.getElementById("go-home-btn").addEventListener("click", handlePurchaseBtn);
```

With the above solution make sure to **remove** the inline HTML attribute <s>onclick="handlePurchaseBtn()"</s> from your button:
`<button id="go-home-btn" type="button">Go home</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply creates a one function

```
function handlePurchaseBtn() {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
}
```

Now pass this function to button tag

```
<button onclick=“handlePurchaseBtn()”>Purchase</button>
```

Now this function is working when you click on the button.